# Need help in proving using mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I got lost when trying to attempt the following question:

The function $\binom{n}{r}$ is defined for positive integers n and r with 1 $\le$ r $\le$ n by $\binom{n}{r}$ = $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.

Use mathematical induction to prove that $\binom{2n}{r}$ $\lt$ $2^{2n-2}$, for all positive integers n$\ge$ 5.

Would really appreciate if anyone could help in the explanation.
Thanks!

Comment: Where'd you get lost?  as there might be several places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove this, I presume you know that $\binom{x}{y}$ is max when $y=\lfloor\frac{x+1}{2}\rfloor$ so you only need to prove $\binom{2n}{n}<2^{2n-2}$ by induction. For $n=5$ the expression is correct and it is easy to check yourself.

$$
\begin{align}
\\
\binom{2n+2}{n+1}&=\frac{2n+2}{n+1}\cdot\binom{2n+1}{n}\\
\\
&<\frac{2n+2}{n+1}\cdot\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\\
\\
&=\frac{2n+2}{n+1}\cdot\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\cdot\binom{2n}{n}\\
\\
&<4\cdot\binom{2n}{n}\\
\\
&<4\cdot 2^{2n-2}\\
\\
&=2^{2(n+1)-2}
\end{align}
$$